# Background of h1 should overlap image

Tags: css, image, background, overlap

currently I'm having some issues with Css on a small website.
I want to display a image, and have a text (h1), which overlaps half of the image. But I also want the text to be in a white box. corrently I"ve solved this which the background-tag, but the image is overlapping the h1-background.

```
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| image            |
|            ______|____________________________
|           | This is the Text, with background |
|            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                  |
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I hope, you understand, what I want to do... I'm thankful for every advice!

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle or similar to reproduce your problem? Thanks

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: http://learnlayout.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example of how it could work

Html

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
<h1>
This is the H1 text
</h1>
```

CSS

```
img{
   float:left;
}
h1{
  float:left;
  margin-left:-20px;
  background:white;
}
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/1b4kx9vd/

Comment: this was the thing I needed. Now I'm just adjusting it for mobile sites! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the box element with the h1 to a position absolute, choose a position you're happy with and have a div container around all elements that is a position relative to keep everything intact for responsiveness.

```
<div style='position: relative;'>
  <img src='images/example.jpg'>
  <div style='position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px;'>
    <h1>Example Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just change the stylings to your perfences.

Answer (score 0):

You can put position: absolute; top: 100px; and left: 100px; in css on your h1 tag.